# Carrierwave: Only run resize process if type is image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

My uploader allows images and pdf's

```
 def extension_whitelist
    %w(pdf jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
```

I need to resize images and process quality. In order to do this, I need to check first if the file is an image.

I've added

```
  version :large, :if => :image? do
    process :quality => 70

    process :resize_to_limit => [1400, 1200]
  end

protected

  def image?(new_file)
    new_file.content_type.include? 'image'
  end
```

However, I don't want a "version". I have the file link on the front-end and the link points to an optimized and not resized version.

How can I check file type without creating a new version of the file?

I've tried

```
if image?
    process :quality => 70

    process :resize_to_limit => [1400, 1200]
  end
```

but I get `No Method Error`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this instead:

```
    process :quality => 70, if: :image?

    process :resize_to_limit => [1400, 1200], if: :image?
```